# Which DB can used with Dascode for Datasource

Tags: iphone

I searched lot of sites for the name of db with iPhone webapp using Dashcode but am not getting satisfactory results from any of sites.

I just want  to know which database can used with iPhone webapp using Dashcode and how to do the connectivity for  the same. Because as far I know that JavaScript is used as language over here so  which db server can be used and how to connect to that db using Dashcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dashcode uses **JSON/XML** for communicating with your application, because dashcode apps run in browser at client side. You need to serve JSON/XML data from you backend application. The application can be written in anything (Ruby on Rails, Python, Java, ASPX, etc.) and the application can connect to any database.

If you have paid Apple developer subscription ([developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com)) you have access to plenty of videos and documents also about Dashcode.

Comment: Thnx for your help. But still there are some confusions , like dashcode is used for client side app ok then how do i serve json/xml data from backend app .What i mean to ask you is we are connecting through an application to dashcode n as u said that application may be written in any thing ok do u mean to say that if i wrote app in "objective c" connect it to db(sqlite3) then how am i going to serve as json/xml data from backend .

Comment: As I said, you need to create web application which serves JSON or XML. I recommend start learning creating web apps. You can try Ruby on Rails which is very simple but powerful web app framework. Visit [http://rubyonrails.org](http://rubyonrails.org) to get started. There are also many high quality free and paid screencasts.